# How can I replace the second button with same name using xpath in Odoo

Tags: xpath, odoo, odoo-12

There two buttons in sale order form in with same name

```
 <button name="action_confirm" id="action_confirm"
                    string="Confirm" class="btn-primary" type="object"
                    attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'not in', ['sent'])]}"/>
 **<button name="action_confirm"
                   string="Confirm" type="object"
                   attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'not in', ['draft'])]}"/>**
```

Need to select second button using xpath and change its attributes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here try this:

```xml
        <!-- make priority bigger to make sure that this XPATH is used after the one
             that adds the button -->
        <field eval="100" name="priority"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr='//buttion[@name="action_confirm"][2]' position='replace'/>
        </field>
```